# how could i possibly solve a null-component issue in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a component "child" which has a cancel button.
Now this component is placed in a state called "newChildComp"

I also have another component called "parent". In the parent component, i have a button that dispatches an event . Here is the event code:

```
protected function addNewChild(event:Event):void
{
 if(currentState!='newChildComp')
   currentState='newChildCom[';
    child["cancelButtonId"].addEventListener("click",cancelButtonHandler);
}
```

so, basically,i am checking to see if the cancel button component in the Child component, while i am still in the parent Compoent,  was clicked, if it was clicked, call the cancelButtonHandler. The problem is by the time the addNewChild handles the event, that cancel button was still null. My question is how do i solve this without using the itemCreationPolicy on the cancel button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just add the click property in mxml...

```
<s:Button click="cancelButtonHandler(event)" />
```

or if you don't want to do that, add event listener to creationComplete or contentCreationComplete on the container and add the event listener there.

```
<s:WhateverComponent includeIn="newChildComp" contentCreationComplete="{cancelButton.addEventListener etc.}"/>
```

does that make sense?